# Django Foreign Key is not relating to users

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, backend

I think this problem has a really simple solution, but I've been on google for a few hours and haven't managed to solve it.

The website I am working on lets user add movies to a watchlist.

It has a search function to look through movies with by title using the OMDB API (which works just fine). It then renders out all the movie posters and titles alongside a button assigned to each movie. The button then takes the img src link, the title and release year of the specific movie and sends an AJAX POST request to the movie_forms form. The request does work as it adds the data to the model but when I send the post request, the foreign key is blank (it shows as '-----' on the admin view). Here's my code!

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.homepage, name='homepage'),
path('signup/', views.signup_view, name='signup'),
path('login/', views.login_view, name='login'),
path('logout/', views.logout_view, name='logout'),
path('movie_form/', views.mlf_view, name='movie_form'),
]
```

views.py

```
def mlf_view(request):
form = MovieListForm()
if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
    print(request.body)
    form = MovieListForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid() and request.is_ajax():
        title = form.cleaned_data.get('title')
        img_link = form.cleaned_data.get('img_link')
        plot = form.cleaned_data.get('plot')
        release_date = form.cleaned_data.get('release_date')
        score = form.cleaned_data.get('score')
        form.user = request.user
        form.save()
        print('form is valud')
        return JsonResponse({"title": title,
            "img_link": img_link,
            "plot": plot,
            "release_date": release_date,
            "score": score}, status=200)
    else:
        print(form.errors)
return render(request, 'main/movie_form.html', {'form': form})
```

models.py

```
class MovieList(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=True)
title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
img_link = models.TextField()
release_year = models.IntegerField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

forms.py

```
class MovieListForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = MovieList
    fields = ['title', 'img_link', 'release_year']
```

GetMovies.js (gets value from input, and renders out movie info)

```
const getMovies= () => {
var title = document.getElementById('title').value
var div = document.getElementById('movies')
console.log(title)


fetch('http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=b53dac20&s=' + title + '&type=movie')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((response) => {
        for (var i = 0; i < response.Search.length; i++) {
            /// create div for each element ///
            var indDiv = document.createElement('div')

            /// creates p tag for title ///
            var movie_title = document.createElement('P')
            movie_title.innerHTML = response.Search[i].Title
            movie_title.id = "title" + i 

            /// creates p tag for release year ///
            var release_year = document.createElement('P')
            release_year.innerHTML = response.Search[i].Year
            release_year.id = 'year' + i

            /// creates img tag with poster link provided by the API and adds unique ID for each img tag ///
            var poster= document.createElement('IMG')
            poster.src = response.Search[i].Poster
            poster.id = 'img' + i

            /// creates button for each div ///
            var button = document.createElement('BUTTON')
            button.classList.add("btn")
            button.value = i 
            button.innerHTML = 'click'
            button.setAttribute('onclick', 'addMovie(this.value)')

            /// appends poster and button to the individual divs and appends those to the main div ///
            indDiv.appendChild(poster)
            indDiv.appendChild(button)
            indDiv.appendChild(movie_title)
            indDiv.appendChild(release_year)
            div.appendChild(indDiv)
            console.log(indDiv)
        }
    })

}
```

AddMovie.js (sends AJAX POST request)

```
function addMovie(value) {
var token = Cookies.get('csrftoken');
$.ajax({
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/movie_form/", 
    type: "POST",
    headers: {"X-CSRFToken": "{{ csrf_token  }}"},
    data: {
        title:$("#title" + value).text(),
        img_link:$("#img" + value).prop('src'),
        release_year:$("#year" + value).text(),
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: token,
        action: "post"
    },
    success:function(data) {
        console.log('worked!')
    },
    error:function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(xhr.statusText)
    }
})
}
```

EDIT: added my html

movie_form

```
<div class="container mt-5 w-50">
<form id="movieForm" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
        <p>{{field.label_tag}}</p>
        {{field}}
    {% endfor %}
    <button>test</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the object's user field not the form's field.

```
if form.is_valid() and request.is_ajax():
    movieList = form.save(commit=False) # commit=False so Django doesn't save the object in the db until we edit the user field.
    movieList.user = request.user
    movieList.save()
```

Comment: When I make these changes I get a 500 Internal Error response.